# removing html tags before printing the output

Tags: html, jquery-templates

I am using Jquery template to print an array of string.. One of the contents stored in the array is of the form "test" .. When they are printed in to the webpage , I dont want it to be showing the html tags. Instead I just want them to print Test. So hwo do I remove these html tags and print the relevant data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripping HTML tags using jQuery is easy:

```
var clean = $('<div><p>Hello</p> <span>World</span></div>').text();
console.log(clean); // logs "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a print stylesheet to hide the elements you do not want to print:

In the HTML page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

print.css

```
#myElement {
    display: none;
}
```